# R shiny - Add logo in browser window using titlePanel

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I want to add a logo to the browser window in the same way as all browser windows are usually displayed:

[image]

`titlePanel` allows to add easily images to the application title, by using:
`titlePanel(title = div(img(src="myAppImage.jpg"), "My App Name")`
It is also possible to add the title that should be displayed by the browser window with `windowTitle` as a parameter.

However, it does not work when adding an image to the browser window. I tried:
`titlePanel(title = div(img(src="myAppImage.jpg"), "My App Name"), windowTitle = div(img(src="myBrowserImage.png"), "My Browser Name"))`. But this gives the following browser name:  <img src ...>

What is the correct way of writing it?

Answer (score 5):

Not inside the `titlePanel` but you can add following inside the ui:

```
tags$head(
        tags$link(rel = "icon", type = "image/png", sizes = "32x32", href = "/myBrowserImage.png"))
```

Also you should put the image inside `www` folder.

Answer (score 0):

As @phago29 indicated, one way to write it is:

```
  useShinyjs(),
  
  ## Window title
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "icon", type = "image/png", sizes = "32x32", href = "myBrowserImage.png")),
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel( title =  div(img(src="myAppImage.png"), 'myAppTitle'), windowTitle = "myBrowserTitle" ), 
  
  # Rest of the UI
)
```

With the png images in a subfolder called "www".